# How can I use this variable on Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, ionic-framework

I have a problem trying to use a variable inside my async function in Vue

this is in methods:

```js
methods: {
   async editar(event) {
            db.collection("products").doc(event).get().then((doc) => {
                const productData = doc.data();
                console.log("Nombre: ", productData.nombre); /* this */
                console.log("Stock: ", productData.stock);
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.log("Error getting document:", error);
            });

            const alert = await alertController.create({
                cssClass: 'alertClass',
                header: 'Editar producto',
                message: '¿Qué deseas cambiar?',
                inputs: [
                    {
                        name: 'nuevoNombre',
                        type: 'text',
                        placeholder: 'Nombre',
                        value: '' /* here */
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'nuevoStock',
                        type: 'number',
                        placeholder: 'Stock'
                    }
                ],
                buttons: [
                    {
                        text: 'Cancelar',
                        role: 'cancel',
                        cssClass: 'secondary',
                        handler: () => {
                            console.log('Cancelado');
                        },
                    },
                    {
                        text: 'Aceptar',
                        handler: (data) => {
                            console.log('Se actualiza el doc: ' + event);
                            db.collection("products").doc(event).update({
                                nombre: data.nuevoNombre,
                                stock: data.nuevoStock
                            }).then(() => {
                                console.log("Nuevo nombre:", data.nuevoNombre);
                                console.log("Nuevo stock:", data.nuevoStock);
                                window.location.reload();
                            }).catch((error) => {
                                console.log("Error al intentar cambiar los valores", error);
                            });
                        },
                    },
                ],
            });
            return alert.present();
    }
}
```

I want to use productData.nombre in the value inside the alertController. I was trying a lot of things but nothing works :(

I hope you can understand my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const productData = doc.data();
```

`const` defined `productData` only can be reference at cloest scope.

At your situation, scope is

```js
db.collection("products").doc(event).get().then((doc) => {
  const productData = doc.data(); // only referenced in this scope (arrow function)
  console.log("Nombre: ", productData.nombre); /* this */
  console.log("Stock: ", productData.stock);
})
```

You can define variable before give it a value like this

```js
async function editar(event) {
  let productData;
  db.collection("products")
    .doc(event)
    .get()
    .then((doc) => {
      productData = doc.data();
      console.log("Nombre: ", productData.nombre); /* this */
      console.log("Stock: ", productData.stock);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log("Error getting document:", error);
    });

  const alert = await alertController.create({
    // your code
  })
}
```

Comment: I try this but I get the next error: `Stock.vue?e81a:87 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'nombre')` I put in the value: productData.nombre

Comment: I solve this not trying to use the variable in "value". Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

1. `db.collection("products")` seems like an async function, using `await` before calling it, or you will miss db data since it's not ready.
2. You should declare variable outside your function which getting db data first, due to [javascript scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope)

Here is a similar easy example on [codepen](https://codepen.io/barney4760/pen/QWqNJrg)